# Bash variable substitution of global variable inside function

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script, in which I wished to reuse variable `b` across different functions, but yet be able to do variable substitution with positional arguments

```
#!/bin/bash

function boo() {
  echo "$1"
  b="this is b and $1"
  echo "$b"
}

function foobar() {
  echo "$1"
  echo "$b"
}
boo "this is argument 1 for boo"
foobar "this is argument 1 for foobar"
```

Current output

```
$ ./script.sh
this is argument 1 for boo
this is b and this is argument 1 for boo
this is argument 1 for foobar
this is b and this is argument 1 for boo
```

How can I modify the script to so that it outputs

```
$ ./script.sh
this is argument 1 for boo
this is b and this is argument 1 for boo
this is argument 1 for foobar
this is b and this is argument 1 for foobar
```

Comment: That's a really weird question. You can just do `printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n' 'this is argument 1' 'this is b and this is argument 1' 'this is b and this is argument 1'`.

Comment: Alternatively, put `b="this is b and $1"` inside the function.

Comment: Alternatively, rewrite it as a Makefile.

Comment: Alternatively, make `b` a function and call it from `boo`.

Comment: Your code does not do what you think it does because `b="this is b and $1"` is called _outside_ of the function where `$1` is just an empty string (unless you call the script with some command line parameters). Like melpomene said: putting `b="this is b and $1"` inside the function might bring you closer to what you expect. Then, the second parameter to the function is no longer needed.

Comment: Alternatively, run your script as `./script.sh 'this is argument 1'`.

Comment: Let me try `b="this is b and $1"` inside the function and see if it fits my more advanced usecase

Comment: Alternatively, change `boo` in the last line to `$(if [ "$1" ]; echo boo; else echo exec bash "$0"; fi)`.

Comment: Or, single quote `b='this is b and $1'` and (not recommended, but..) use `eval` in the function, e.g. `eval echo "$2"` and `eval echo "$b"`

Comment: Ah, so there is an actual problem you haven't told us about, which makes this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Elaborate the problem further

Comment: No, that's just adding more (seemingly random) constraints to your problem. My first comment still applies. "*How can I modify my program so that it outputs X*" can always be "solved" by doing `print X`. If you want to get a sensible answer, show your actual problem.

Comment: Used a function as suggested by @melpomene. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/a/51463518/207502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [melponene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) for suggesting a function. This seems to be what I require. Instead of relying on a common variable for variable expansion, a function is more suitable

```
#!/bin/bash
function b_func(){
 echo "this is b and $*"
}

function boo() {
  echo "$1"
  b_var="$(b_func $1)"
  echo "$b_var"
}

function foobar() {
  echo "$1"
  b_var="$(b_func $1)"
  echo "$b_var"
}
boo "this is argument 1 for boo"
foobar "this is argument 1 for foobar"
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh
this is argument 1 for boo
this is b and this is argument 1 for boo
this is argument 1 for foobar
this is b and this is argument 1 for foobar
```